# How to Retrieve Power BI API Access Token without Manual Login?

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, postman, powerbi-api

Unable to retrieve Access Token from Power BI API, making use of Azure Active Directory Details.

I'm currently making use of Postman to first test if I can Successfully request an Access Token form Power BI.

[Postman GET Request:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuan0.jpg)

I'm getting this error that I "must use multi-factor authentication to access" application name.

I am able to make use of JavaScript that allows me to manually direct to a Microsoft login page in order to authenticate and then redirect me back to where I was.

The issue is that I don't want my clients to have to login to see Power BI reports, for they do not have Power BI login.

I am trying to automatically authenticate myself with the provided login details used in the [Postman GET Request:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuan0.jpg) without having to redirect to a Microsoft login page.

This is the closest I've come to actually gaining an Access Token without being redirected to Microsoft login page. [Postman GET Request:]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created an **Azure AD Multi-Tenant application and granted API permissions** like below:

[image]

Now I tried to generate the **access token via ROPC flow**:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token

client_id:ClientID
resource:https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api
grant_type:password
username:ruk@xxx.onmicrosoft.com
password:***
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

But I got the **error** like below:

[image]

> **Note** that: ROPC flow doesn't support user accounts with MFA enabled. If you are trying to login to the application using ROPC flow then it will be blocked with the error. Refer to the [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc).

**To resolve the error**, disable the MFA for the user like below:

[image]

Disabled **MFA** successfully like below:

[image]

After the above changes, **I am able to generate access token successfully** like below:

[image]

When I decoded the token, **aud** is `https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api`

[image]

Alternatively, you can make of any other Token grant flows refer the below **MsDoc**:

[Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)